# Accessing structure elements via double pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list, double-pointer

I'm implementing linked lists using structures. I have a structure -

```
typedef struct llist node;
typedef node *nodeptr;
struct llist
{
    int data;
    nodeptr next;
};
```

Now lets say I declare a variable `nodeptr *ptr;`. How do I access the members `data` and `next` using `ptr`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You deference the first pointer and then the second one.

To access the data and next in the structure statement would like this

```
(*ptr)->data = 5;
(*ptr)->next = temp;
```

brackets around ptr is required since `->`  has higher priority than  `*`.

**`->`** is equivalent to writing **`*.`**  (e.g. `ptr->data` is the same as `*ptr.data`).

Comment: So say I want to allocate some memory to a `ptr`, is `(*ptr)=(nodeptr *)malloc(sizeof(nodeptr))` correct?

Comment: Ya u can try that but since ptr will pointing to random address u may get segmentation fault so it's safe should create a pointer to a struct first then allocate its address to ptr.