# Not able to assign values to structure fields using double pointers? (C)

Tags: c, pointers, io, structure

I'm probably mssing something super obvious here, but I've been at this for hours and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Basically, I have a double pointer of type `student`, called `class_list`.

`student` is a structure with several fields such as `ID`, `first_name`, `last_name`.

I need to read data from a file and place this data in the respective fields of each structure `student`.

This is my implementation (By the way, the first value in the file contains the number of students, hence   the line `fscanf(input_file, "%d", sizePtr);`):

```
student** create_class_list(char *filename, int *sizePtr) {

    printf("FUNCTION CALL **\n\n");

    FILE *input_file = fopen(filename, "r");

    fscanf(input_file, "%d", sizePtr);
    int totalStudents = *sizePtr;
    student **class_list = calloc(totalStudents, sizeof(student));

    while (totalStudents) {

        fscanf(input_file, "%d", &(*class_list)->student_id);
        fscanf(input_file, "%s", (*class_list)->first_name);
        fscanf(input_file, "%s", (*class_list)->last_name);
        class_list++;

        totalStudents--;
    
    }
    fclose(input_file);


    return class_list;
}
```

I tried my best looking for the answer through other stack posts, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398105/accessing-structure-elements-via-double-pointers-in-c) one seems to illustrate my problem clearly. However, I have already tried the their solution by first dereferencing the double pointer: `(*class_list)->student_id`, but alas I still get an issue when executing the code.

Comment: Is using calloc (with the first parameter being the total number of students and the second parameter being the size of 1 student) not the correct way to allocate memory?

Comment: if you want to use `student** class_list ` you should allocate memory to `student* class_list ` first then allocate memory to `student** class_list `, i think you need NOT to go with double pointer(we can do, but need to as mentioned before), single pointer `student* class_list ` is enough for traversing through the list of records.

Answer (score 2):

At least: Incorrect allocation

```
//                                              This is the size of a structure  
// student **class_list = calloc(totalStudents, sizeof(student));
student **class_list = calloc(totalStudents, sizeof *class_list );
//                                           This is correct, size of a pointer
```

---

I recommend a new approach.  Allocate for an array of `student`, not an array of pointers to `student`.

```
// student** create_class_list(char *filename, int *sizePtr) {
student* create_class_list(char *filename, int *sizePtr) {
  *sizePtr = 0;
  printf("FUNCTION CALL **\n\n");
  FILE *input_file = fopen(filename, "r");
  if (input_file == NULL) return NULL;  // Check return value

  int totalStudents = 0;
  fscanf(input_file, "%d", &totalStudents);
  student *cl = calloc(totalStudents, sizeof *cl);

  if (cl) {
    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < totalStudents; i++) {
      // Check return value of `fscanf()` (Should also do so above)
      if (fscanf(input_file, "%d%s%s", // Better to use width limits with %s
          &cl[i]->student_id, cl[i]->first_name, cl[i]->last_name) != 3) break;
    }
    *sizePtr = i; // Record how many were read 
  }

  fclose(input_file);
  return cl;
}
```